# Filter map markers with spinner

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps

I have a spinner that allows me to select a company type : Car Center vs Truck Center.

I pull the addresses from JSON and display them with map markers in an AsyncTask. When I use the code below without the do while the map displays all markers regardless of company type. So I decided to include a do while loop to add map objects while the company in the JSON is a "Car Center". I will do likewise with "Truck Center".

My problem is with the do while loop no markers show up on the map at all, but without the do while loop all the markers show up.

```
do {  
    data1 = new LocationData(lati, longi, nameFirst1 + " " + nameLast1,otherinfo); 
   }
while (company1.equals("Car Center"));

locationList.add(data1);

if (str.equals("Car Center")) {  
    publishProgress(data1);
}else {}                         
}


public   LocationData onProgressUpdate(LocationData data1 ) {

return data1; 

}
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
for(LocationData data1 : locationList){
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
     .position(new LatLng(data1.getLat(), data1.getLongitude()))
     .title(data1.getName())
     .snippet(data1.getOther()));   
}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {   
str =(String)arg0.getSelectedItem();                 
Log.d("Spinner choice", str);           
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easy to tell what is wrong since you have not posted all of your AsyncTask. For instance:

- How is **company1** fetched and written
- When is **str** written

What happens if you in your processing simply do?
*Assuming company1 is re-written for all fetched companies in JSON*

```
if (company1.equals("Car Center")) {{  
    locationList.add(new LocationData(lati, longi, nameFirst1 + " " + nameLast1,otherinfo));
    publishProgress(data1);
}
```

Otherwise, written in pseudo code:

```
fetch all companies

int totalCompanies = companies.size();
int progress = 0;

for all companies {
    progress++;
    if company equals("Car Center") {  
        locationList.add(new LocationData(lati, longi, nameFirst1 + " " + nameLast1,otherinfo));

        // you do not have to use publishProgress
        // but if you do I though giving a percentage of progress instead of data1 makes sense
        publishProgress((progress/totalCompanies)*100); 
    }
}
```

I suspect that by using a while loop you do not get any markers at all, possibly because the first element is not equals Car Center, which makes the while loop stop.

I am still abit confused about your code as it seems as if you use a new AsyncTask for each company, having only a single element, which you then throw a while loop after. Might very well be that I miss something and will happily come with more suggestions if the above does not help.

Then I just need you to post the full code in order for me to understand the logic behind it.